# Open file in new split from "Navigate to class" menu

Tags: rubymine, jetbrains-ide

Is there a way to open a file in new split form `Navigate to class` modal?

[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible currently, please vote for [IDEA-194156](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-194156) and linked tickets